# Linux redhat crontab + run script with arguments

Tags: shell-script, rhel, cron

I add the following line to the red-hat crontab

in order to run the script **/var/scripts/info_from_all_sites.bash** every Friday at **00:00 night**

script should get as argument the file -  /var/RT/names.txt

so script will read all info from this file,

```
 0 0 * * 5   /var/scripts/info_from_all_sites.bash /var/RT/names.txt 1>/dev/null 2>&1
```

my question is - is it OK to add the file as argument to the script in the crontab ?

Or maybe I need to put the file with double quotes as

```
 0 0 * * 5   /var/scripts/info_from_all_sites.bash "/var/RT/names.txt" ?
```

Comment: @Rahul Why would that be a good thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is ok to do this.

From the [`crontab(5)` manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html):

> The "sixth" field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be
>    run.  The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or a
>    `%` character, will be executed by `/bin/sh` or by the shell specified
>    in the `SHELL` variable of the cronfile.  A `%` character in the
>   command, unless escaped with a backslash (`\`), will be changed into
>    newline characters, and all data after the first `%` will be sent to
>    the command as standard input.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue where I was using the following crontab:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```

And inside the bash script I was using this to get the -f option:

```
while getopts ":f" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            force_full=1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

So I noticed that the option wasn't being honored when I ran this through cron for some reason.  Well, adding /bin/bash to the cronjob fixed it right up.  The new crontab is:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /bin/bash /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```